# Ideal gas and piston

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In cylinder with movable piston a gas is closed. It has been noticed that if cylinder was thermally isolated, quasi-statistical growth of volume resulted in reduction of pressure according to equation: 
$$p^{3} V^{5} = const$$ 
Find work done over this system and heat transfered to it for three different processes presented on the graph(ADB, ACB and linear AB).
[image: Graph 1]

**My attempts to solve this exercise:**

I found a first law of thermodynamics equation:
$$dU = dQ - dW,$$
where $dW = - pdV$ and $dQ = TdS$ (I guess).
I am also aware of existing an ideal gas law:
$$pV =nRT.$$
I think I could calculate $dW$ easily (with information given on the graph), then use the depency of pressure and volume (given by first equation) and with the help of ideal gas law - find a temperature, but what with $dS$ then? It's necessary to find the heat transfer $dQ$. I will be glad for every help.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the change in temperature in each case, you use $$\Delta T=\frac{\Delta (PV)}{nR}$$  To get the change in internal energy in each case, you use $$\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T$$  To get $C_v$, you use $$C_v=\frac{3}{2}R$$  To get the work, you use $$W=\int{PdV}$$To get the heat, you use $$Q=\Delta U+W$$

Comment: But is it possible to find n in this equations? There aren’t number of moles and type of gas given exercise

Comment: If you do it algebraically, the n cancels out.

Comment: To the person who gave this a down vote:  Which part of the analysis were you not able to follow?

Comment: Most users who vote negatively do not respond.

Answer (score -1):

Work is the area under the graph P-V. So you just need to integrate (there're lots of triangles, use them).

Comment: So for example the work done would be:
$$W = \fraq{1}{2} \cdot ( * \cdot 10^{-3} - 10^{-3} ) \cdot (10^{5} - \fraq{1}{32} \cdot 10^{5} ) \approx 339 J,$$ $$ W_{ACB} = - W_{ADB} \approx -339J,$$ and what about AB?

Comment: Edit your comment, in order to get it in latex, change "fraq" for "frac" (Otherwise, it's realliy diffult to read).

Comment: I did it one time( also incorrect) and I can't do it again(newbie's things) so I will just try to rewrite my comment:

So for example the work done would be:
$$W_{ADB} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( 8 \cdot 10^{-3} - 10^{-3} ) \cdot (10^{5} - \frac{1}{32} \cdot 10^{5} ) \approx 339 J,$$ $$ W_{ACB} = - W_{ADB} \approx -339J,$$ and what about AB? Does $W_{AB}$ equal $W_{ACB}$ (same area)? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Sorry for the hint, isn't a hundred per hundred correct. From $A$ to $B$ is suposed to evole according to $P^3V^5=K_1$. However, you can determine this constant, and then define the curve $P(V)=\frac{K_2}{V^{\frac{5}{3}}}$ and integrate (it isn't a triangle now). The work done from $A$ to $B$ deppends on the path, however you can find integrating  (and plotting triangles), assuming that your base level is $P=0$

Comment: Does the $K_{2} = p_{B}^{3} \cdot V_{B}^{5}$?

Comment: No, it's $\sqrt[3]{p_B^3V_B^5}$ (my curve is $P(V)$ not $P^3(V)$)

Comment: Ok, so the work done in AB process would be
$$W_{AB} = \int_{10^{3}}^{8 \cdot 10^{-3}} \frac{K_{2}}{v^{\frac{5}{3}}}dv ?$$